# angular TAB is not working in IE8 giving IE alert "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using windows 8 machine. I am trying angular/twitter bootstrap TAB on IE8.
When i am trying to select TAB(using mouse click) it is giving me and IE alert "**Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer**".
following is the code,

`<!doctype html>`
`<html ng-app="plunker">`
  `<head>`
  `<link href="bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
    `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>`
    `<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>`
    `<script type="text/javascript">`
    `angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);`
    `var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {`
      `$scope.panes = [`
        `{ title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },`
        `{ title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2" }`
      `];`
     `$scope.clicked = function()`
     `{`
        `alert('clicked');`
     `}`
    `};`
    `</script>`

`</head>`
  `<body>`

`<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">`
    `<div tabs>`
        `<div pane heading="Static title">Static content</div>`
       `<div pane ng-repeat="pane in panes" heading="{{pane.title}}" active="pane.active">{{pane.content}}</div>`
    `</div>`
   `<div class="row-fluid">`
       `<button class="btn" ng-click="panes[0].active = true">Select second tab</button>`
        `<button class="btn" ng-click="panes[1].active = true">Select third tab</button>`
   `</div>`
`</div>`
  `</body>`
`</html>`

Please let me know am i missing any IE settings or its css issue ?
Other that IE8 on every browser its working fine. with out any error message

After verification i found that when TAB control rendered on UI its creates an following html
`<li ng-class="{active:pane.selected}" ng-repeat="pane in panes" class="ng-scope active">`
      `<a ng-click="select(pane)" class="ng-binding">Static title</a>`
    `</li>`

If you observe anchor tag dont have "**href**" and i guess that is an issue. so how we can overcome this issue and make TAB working in IE8.

Comment: Problem is with the anchor href="unsafe:". If u observed final html anchor tag have href="unsafe:" which cause an issue. to solve this if u able to add href="javascript:void(0);" will solve u r problem

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with the anchor href="unsafe:". If u observed final html anchor tag have href="unsafe:" which cause an issue. to solve this if u able to add href="javascript:void(0);" will solve u r problem